# JavaScript and CSS style not working on my "Google Sites" page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, show-hide, google-sites

I have links that once click it will unhide content, and  then all content will show after clicked again. I am using  on google docs and it will not work. I am also using CSS . The links show but the javascript and CSS won't compile for me or others.

```js
function toggle() {
 var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText");
 var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
 if(ele.style.display == "block") {
      ele.style.display = "none";
  text.innerHTML = "Musis List";
   }
 else {
  ele.style.display = "block";
  text.innerHTML = "Musis List &#9660;";
 }
}
```

```css
#title a:link { color: #38761D; text-decoration: none !important; }
#title a:visited { 
 color: #38761D; text-decoration: none !important; 
}
#title a:hover{ 
 color: #4EA628; 
 background-color:transparent;
 text-decoration: none !important; 
}
#title a:active { 
 color: #4EA628; text-decoration: none !important; 
} 
#title a {
 text-decoration: none !important; 
 display:block;
 border-bottom: 0px solid #38761D;
 font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: large; 
 line-height: 1.26;
}
```

```html
<center>
<div id="title" >
<a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle();">Musis List</a>
</div>
<div id="toggleText" style="display: none">
Here will be a list of music....
</div>

<br />
<br />
<br />

<script language="javascript"> 
function toggle1(id) {
 var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText1");
 var text = document.getElementById("displayText1");
 if(ele.style.display == "block") {
      ele.style.display = "none";
  text.innerHTML = "Video List";
   }
 else {
  ele.style.display = "block";
  text.innerHTML = "Video List &#9660;";
 }
} 
</script>

<div id="title" >
<a id="displayText1" href="javascript:toggle1(1);">Video List</a>
</div>
<div id="toggleText1" style="display: none">Here will be a list of videos....</div>


</center>
```

Let me know, if anyone can help. I'd appreciated mates.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a link, that is very helpful with all the step:

http://www.k8oms.net/gadget-editor

Check it out!

Best,
David Conde

Comment: The referred solution depends on a deprecated Google Drive feature, by the other hand, answer should include the most relevant parts of the linked resource.